# AEM : Removing auto generated divs

Tags: aem

I am including a component like this:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${selectList-1}" varStatus="loopSubmenu">
<sling:include path="submenu_${loopSubmenu.index}" resourceType="aemdevcenter/components/content/global-header/submenu" />
</c:forEach>
```

and to get rid of the auto generated divs I have included the below code in my global.jsp

```
<%

if (WCMMode.fromRequest(request) != WCMMode.EDIT && WCMMode.fromRequest(request) != WCMMode.DESIGN && WCMMode.fromRequest(request) != WCMMode.DISABLED && WCMMode.fromRequest(request) != WCMMode.PREVIEW) {
    IncludeOptions.getOptions(request, true).forceSameContext(Boolean.TRUE);                            
}

%>
```

But I am still not able to get rid of the auto generated divs and this is messing with the styles. Any ideas ? I am using AEM 6.1

Also, when I try to use cq:noDecoration I lose the authoring ability.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include following code in your Global.jsp to remove unwanted divs in preview mode:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${ requestScope['com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode']=='EDIT' || requestScope['com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode']=='DESIGN'}">
    <c:if test="${componentContext!=null}">
        <% componentContext.setDefaultDecorationTagName("div"); %>
    </c:if>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <c:if test="${componentContext!=null}">
        <% componentContext.setDefaultDecorationTagName(""); %>
    </c:if>
</c:otherwise>
```

For more details, please have a look at this [post](https://mkbansal.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/aem-remove-wrapper-html-tags-in-preview-mode/).

Answer (score 0):

Slice, until its [3.2](https://cognifide.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SLICE/CQ+Taglibs+-+3.2) version, provided a set of taglibs and functionality that could help achieve what you want. The tag 'cog:include' has the parameter 'enableDecoration' which allow to remove the decoration, for example:

```
<cog:include enableDecoration="${conditional}" path="some/path/" resourceType="my/component" />
```

other option, still using slice 3.2 is to set the property 'cog:enableDecorationInModes' in the component node and then use cog:include tag without the 'enableDecoration' parameter:

```
<cog:include path="some/path/" resourceType="my/component" />
```

Unfortunately this functionality was removed from newer slice versions, but it is possible to extract its code and use it.